# Reading Value from UIDatePicker UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Trying to get the amount of time selected by a user from a UIDatePicker set to mode:"UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer" in InterFace Builder. Some other stacks say to just check the value of the property countDownDuration on the object.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *hereIsThePicker;
...
NSLog(@"%f", self.hereIsThePicker.countDownDuration);
```

But this value often reports a range of values, I've seen numbers such as 70, 80, 113, etc for a selection of "0 Hours, 0 Minutes". So apparently countDownDuration is not what I need.

Does anyone have any hints or clues on how to use UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer and convert the selection to number of seconds selected? so 1 Minute Selected = 60 Seconds, or 1 Hour 5 Minutes Selected = 3900 seconds ?

Been trying to track this down for 2 days now and just can't seem to get my head around what is going on.

Here is a screenshot of an example application that I setup that just has these two components. You can see the IBOutlet, and a button with an IBAction that is fetching the time and NSLogging it to the bottom of the screen:

[image: UIDatePicker TimerMode]

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying random stuff for days, the simple answer, for whatever reason is you need to set a value to countDownDuration, even if you don't need to:

```
[self.timerPicker setCountDownDuration:60.0f]; //Defaults to 1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

In your header .h file put this

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    __weak IBOutlet UIPickerView *datePick;
    NSMutableArray *hoursArray;
    NSMutableArray *minsArray;

    NSTimeInterval interval;
}
- (IBAction)calculateTimeFromPicker:(id)sender;
```

in your .m file put this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //initialize arrays
    hoursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    minsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *strVal = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i<61; i++)
    {
        strVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

        //NSLog(@"strVal: %@", strVal);

        //Create array with 0-12 hours
        if (i < 13)
        {
            [hoursArray addObject:strVal];
        }

        //create arrays with 0-60 mins
        [minsArray addObject:strVal];
    }


    NSLog(@"[hoursArray count]: %d", [hoursArray count]);
    NSLog(@"[minsArray count]: %d", [minsArray count]);

}

//Method to define how many columns/dials to show
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

// Method to define the numberOfRows in a component using the array.
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent :(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    if (component==0)
    {
        return [hoursArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [minsArray count];
    }

}

// Method to show the title of row for a component.
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (component) 
    {
        case 0:
            return [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [minsArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)calculateTimeFromPicker:(id)sender
{

    NSString *hoursStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[hoursArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

    NSString *minsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[minsArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];


    int hoursInt = [hoursStr intValue];
    int minsInt = [minsStr intValue];

    interval = 0 + (minsInt*60) + (hoursInt*3600);

    NSString *totalTimeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",interval];

}
```